# Stop MKMap Zooming in on load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This may be a simple question but I cant find the answer in the documentation or through a search.

When my map loads it zooms in from far to my set region. How do I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `animated` to `NO` when calling `setRegion:animated:`. As follows:

```
[map setRegion:region animated:NO];
```